# Spark - select multiple columns from array object

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset with following schema

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- subEntities: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- subEntityId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- subEntityName: string (nullable = true)
```

`dataset.select($"id", $"name", $"subEntities.subEntityId", $"subEntities.subEntityName")` put `subEntityId` and `subEntityName` into separate arrays. How to select multiple columns and put them into single array?

Comment: hey @coderz, did any of the next answers help you?

Answer (score 2):

If working on `Spark >= 2.4` you can use the [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) function to generate an array which contains a subset of the original array's fields:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr

dataset.withColumn("newArray", expr("transform(subEntities, i -> struct(i.subEntityId, i.subEntityName))"))

// or with select
dataset.select(
        $"id", 
        $"name",
        expr("transform(subEntities, i -> struct(i.subEntityId, i.subEntityName))").as("newArray")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `.withColumn("status",col("subEntities").getField("status"))`
2. `.withColumn("subEntityId",col("subEntities").getField("subEntityId"))`

To extract value out of your array

Below is working example

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object ExplodeArrauy {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess

    import spark.implicits._

    val df = List(bean57("1",Array(bean55("aaa",2),bean55("aaa1",21))),
      bean57("2",Array(bean55("bbb",3),bean55("bbb3",31)))).toDF

    df
      .withColumn("status",col("subEntities").getField("status"))
      .withColumn("subEntityId",col("subEntities").getField("subEntityId"))
      .show()

  }

}


case class bean57(id:String,subEntities:Array[bean55])

case class bean55(status: String,subEntityId:Long)
```